# Performance for partial search mechanism, time difference between keystrokes

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have a private method that is triggered when a user searches for a group Name in the active directory. The seach is initiatied when the text in the 'TxtBoxGroupNameSearch' changes.

```
    private void SearchForAGroup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
       dataGridGroupNameList.Rows.Clear();

       try
          {
            string searchString = TxtBoxGroupNameSearch.Text;
            var partialGroupNameMatches = AllGroupsResults.Cast<SearchResult>()
                                          .Where(sr => sr.Properties["name"].Cast<String>()
                                          .Any(s => s.Contains(searchString)));

            object[] fields = new object[2];
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in partialGroupNameMatches)
               {
                  fields[0] = i;
                  i++;
                  fields[1] = item.Properties["name"][0].ToString();
                  dataGridGroupNameList.Rows.Add(fields);
               }    

            groupName = partialGroupNameMatches.ToList()[0]
                        .Properties["name"][0]
                        .ToString(); // gets the first GroupName on the grid

            GetUsers(groupName); // calls a get user method - LDAP query to get all users 
                                    specific to the 'groupName'

            BindToUserListGrid(AllGroupUsers); // Binds all users to a 2nd gridView  
         }
      catch { }
      Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
   }
```

All works great. The code is functional. However there is a performance issue at hand. Everytime the text in the textbox changes, the method is initiated, all partial matches are found, bound to the primary gridview, then all users specific to the first GroupName on the newly bound gridView  are queried using ldap. The list of users are then bound to a secondary UserList GridView.

I have added the wait cursor to let the user know, that things are being done in the background during the wait time... but I am wondering if the process can be improved to reduce the number of times the secondary list of users is queried and then bound to the secondary gridView.

### My theory is either:-

1) Introduce a wait time so that the secondary list of users is only queried after waiting for a specific amount of time (say 1s).... Example :- user types 'a', then 'b' and then waits for a 1s before typing anything else... only at this 1s wait do we query the list of users specific to the first groupName match starting with 'ab'... instead of the current way, where we would be querying the list of users for the first keystroke 'a', then bind them to the secondary grid. then again query the list of users for second keystroke 'a' + 'b', then bind to the secondary grid... thus reducing time by 1/2.

To Calculate TimeSpan between two different keystrokes can be tricky:-

```
 DateTime a = new DateTime();
 DateTime b = new DateTime();
 a = b; // previous stroke time
 b = DateTime.Now; // current stroke time
 if (b.Subtract(a).TotalSeconds > 2)
 {
     groupName = partialGroupNameMatches.ToList()[0].Properties["name"][0].ToString();
     GetUsers(groupName);
     BindToUserListGrid(AllGroupUsers);
  }
```

However there is a couple of issues with the above methodology... primarily the distinction between keystrokes, silence and the first keystroke (ever) and the last keystroke (until quite bit of time surpasses). I would like to improve this process. Suggestions are most welcome.

2) or threading.

I would like some possible advice from some of the more experts in the field.

Comment: I think your 1) approach is correct, but you might consider adding some caching as well. Check if the newest string coming in contains the current string. If it does, you only need to search your existing list, rather than making the whole round trip back to LDAP. That approach does assume that a longer string will never match a larger result set than a short one.

Comment: I cannot use a simple thread.sleep methodology... how would I implement the sleep method instead between keystrokes ?